# Spring MVC : How to Validate Nested Bean Property with Ajax

Tags: ajax, validation, spring-mvc

Suppose that I have these classes :

```
class Child {
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5)
    private String name;

    @NotNull        
    private Parent parent;

    //getter and setter methods
}

class Parent {
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    //getter and setter methods
}
```

Here is the handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, ?> add(@Valid Child child, BindingResult result) {

    Map<String, ?> out = new LinkedHashMap<String, ?>();

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        Map<String, String> errors = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for (FieldError error : result.getFieldErrors()) {
           errors.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        out.put("success", false);
        out.put("errors", errors);
        return out;
    } else {
        out.put("success", true);
    }

    return out;

}
```

If I submit this data to add a child via Ajax (POST):

```
name = testtesttest
parent.id = 3
```

Everything is OK. The new child is saved successfully.

But If don't include the `parent.id` (only `name` is set)

```
name = testtesttest
```

The validation result return this:

```
"errors":{"parent":"may not be null"}
```

Note the `"parent"` property in that JSON. It's supposed to return `parent.id` not `parent`.

It causes problem as the field on client-side script (HTML) has the name `parent.id` not `parent`.

Any suggestion How to solve this??

Thank you.

**NOTE:**
If I change the submitted data to this:

```
name = testtesttest
parent = 3
```

I got the other error:

```
{"success":false,"errors":{"parent":"Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.test.entity.Parent' for property 'parent'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.test.entity.Parent] for property 'parent': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"}}
```

Comment: try using @modelattribute as documented in Spring reference doc.